# How to get the phone local number from international phone number with IoNIC

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm using IONIC4 in my project, I managed to get all the countries with its own CallingCodes and country code, Now I'm getting stuck to get the local phone format(a mask to display in the placeholder) for the selected country.

I give an example, suppose that the selected country is France, its country code is: FR and its calling code is (33) so how I get the following mask:

```
07 45 85 96 32
```

Is there a way to do that using IONIC please ?

Answer (score 0):

You could install libphonenumber: npm install --save-prod google-libphonenumber

Then, you can use the AsYouTypeFormatter to mask the number as it's being typed.

```
// Require `AsYouTypeFormatter`.
const AsYouTypeFormatter = require('google-libphonenumber').AsYouTypeFormatter;
const formatter = new AsYouTypeFormatter('US');

console.log(formatter.inputDigit('2')); // => 2
console.log(formatter.inputDigit('0')); // => 20
console.log(formatter.inputDigit('2')); // => 202
console.log(formatter.inputDigit('-')); // => 202-
console.log(formatter.inputDigit('4')); // => 202-4
console.log(formatter.inputDigit('5')); // => 202-45
console.log(formatter.inputDigit('6')); // => 202-456
console.log(formatter.inputDigit('-')); // => 202-456-
console.log(formatter.inputDigit('1')); // => 202-456-1
console.log(formatter.inputDigit('4')); // => 202-456-14
console.log(formatter.inputDigit('1')); // => 202-456-141
console.log(formatter.inputDigit('4')); // => 202-456-1414

// Cleanup all input digits from instance.
formatter.clear();
```

To get the format in France, simply pass 'FR' to the formatter

```
const formatter = new AsYouTypeFormatter('FR');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesnt make sens to me, what i'm looking for is, from the country code 'FR' get an exemple of a phone number, can u explain please?

Comment: getExampleNumber(country, examples)
Returns an example phone number for a country. Returns an instance of PhoneNumber class. Will return undefined if country doesn't exist or isn't supported by this library.

import examples from 'libphonenumber-js/examples.mobile.json'
import { getExampleNumber } from 'libphonenumber-js'
 
const phoneNumber = getExampleNumber('FR', examples)
 
phoneNumber.formatNational() === '8 (912) 345-67-89'

Comment: Go to this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js.        Ctrl+f getExampleNumber.     This is the method that will provide an example number based on the country that is passed into the param